# Need to always round up in SQL

Tags: sql, rounding

The decimal value needs to round up to the nearest integer, it doesn't matter if the fractional part is greater or less than .5.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  MONTH_ 
        , COST 
        , DISC_COST / COST AS 'amount' 
        , DISC_COST 
        , PROFIT  
FROM    arr 
WHERE   MONTH_ LIKE 'JANU%'
```

These are the result:

```
MONTH_  COST    amount      DISC_COST   PROFIT
January 200     1              200       70
January 3500    2,414285714    8450     7250
January 4500    1              4500     2900
January 28500   0,631578947    18000    11200
January 600     1              600      100
```

Comment: Such rounding is usually referred to as "Ceiling". In order to assist (if that's not enough clue by itself), we'd need to know which database product you're using (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, MySql, etc)

Comment: What is the database you use? MySql? Oracle? etc.

Comment: @vahdet It is sql

Comment: It is `CEILING` for [SQL Server](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_ceiling.asp), `CEIL` for [MySql, Oracle and Postgres](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/arithmetic-functions/ceil-with-positive-value.php). And no, __SQL__ is the language, not the database.

Comment: @ArailymMedetkazina SQL is a *language*, that has different flavours depending on the *engine*. So the question is: do you use MySQL? Oracle? PostgreSQL? MariaDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CEIL()` function (MySQL/Postgres).
Use `CEILING()` function (MS SQL).

```
SELECT 
    MONTH_ , 
    COST , 
    CEIL((DISC_COST / COST)) AS 'amount' , 
    DISC_COST , PROFIT  
FROM 
    arr 
WHERE 
    MONTH_ LIKE 'JANU%'
```

Comment: `ROUND` won't make a 2.4 a 3.

Comment: try CEIL() function

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: This is why you should *wait* whilst a question is *unclear*, rather than rushing to provide a (possibly useful, possibly not) answer.

Comment: @rahulJain unfortunately , in sql cannot use CEIL()

Answer (score -1):

You can use trunc() to make it integer value by just cut off the decimal values.

```
SELECT MONTH_ , COST , TRUNC(DISC_COST / COST) AS 'amount' , DISC_COST , PROFIT  FROM arr WHERE MONTH_ LIKE 'JANU%'
```

Comment: `TRUNC` won't make a 0.6 a 1.